# Adding custom events in html tag

Tags: javascript, html

How to add custom event in html tag like:

```
<button oncustomevent="doSomething('string')">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your custom event ? can you give example?

Comment: You can add like above but it won't work if you fire your custom event. It is always better to use JavaScript :)

Comment: I want to fire an event after 5 sec on click event. I know it is possible in javascript using setTimeout(), but I just want to add an event onafterclick()

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of JavaScript :p ... No Seriously, why do you need a custom event.. whatever events that were best possible is already provided by JS.. If you need some action then probably functions would help...